# how to start a feature in magento

Tags: php, plugins, magento, geolocation

I would like to set up a zip locator functionnality straight from the home page of a pizza magento website.
The idea is to redirect user depending on his postcode to a specific store (I set up multistore option in the backend, each store match a real physical store) so he can be deliver (or not) by the nearest pizza shop.

The idea is pretty much simple but i didn't find any good ressources abording the subject...So if you have good link/tutorial/how to, or know the basic step to build it from scratch..like builiding a plugin or surcharge precise core lib..

Thx

Comment: THe knowledge base has all the base Magento architecture information you'd need to build something like this. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento

Comment: ok but I still have to write a plugin, or I can override existing classes of core magento ?How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on store restriction extension. It is the same way you have to follow, you check a parameter ( a session or a zip code) and redirect the customer to the right store.

Comment: I just install it and start to play around with it but it seems not working, i.e, I control select all the stores from "Restricted store", then I select all users type in "Allowed Customer Groups" except General, I empty cache, refresh index, going back to frontend, logged in with a general account and I'm still allow to visit the store....Do I miss something ? thx